# CrossData in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, business-intelligence

it's the first time that I make a question here.

I've been working with [Metabase](https://www.metabase.com/) whith some databases on Postgres in my work.
I have a demand that is cross data among tables, but the main table have no Date column to join with the others.
The main way, which is the pattern is JOIN with de calendar_aux tablet among a Date camp.

The main table, named shop_dre_operational has the following structure

```
year january february march april may june july august september october november december
```

Returning values like this:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIkIs.png)

All the months are columns including the year, how can i transform thi in a date to join with other tables an select some values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` to assemble the data in a different format. For example:

```
select *
from (
  select make_date(ano, 1, 1) as date, jan as amount from t
  union all select make_date(ano, 2, 1), fev from t
  union all select make_date(ano, 3, 1), mar from t
  ...
  union all select make_date(ano, 12, 1), dez from t
) x
where ...
group by ...
order by ...
```

Will produce a data set with two columns: `date` and `amount` that you can use in any query.

Comment: I have implemented this solution, replacing the  `from t` for other ambient variables that i have used in the code. It worked, thanks!